# Use a trigger to count the number of items after insert element in other table

Tags: sql, select, triggers, insert, firebird

I have two tables:

```
salary_class ( class char(1), how_many integer)

employee_tester ( name varchar(50), salary integer )
```

After insert a new employee to the database, according with his salary increment the value "how_many" must be incremented. The salary_class have the different types of salaries like less than 8K the class is "D", between 8K and 12K the class is "C" and so on.

The problem is that I am having problems to create a trigger to to this job.

```
set term # ;
create trigger tr_salary_class_insert for EMPLOYEE_TESTER after insert
as
    declare variable letter char(1);
begin
    select class from f_class(new.SALARY) into :letter;


end #
set term ; #
```

f_class is one stored procedure that returns the char according to the salary.

Comment: Could you describe what problem you are facing? Currently it isn't really clear how we can (or should) help you.

Comment: The problem I am having is that I am having problems understanding the problem you are having.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see you just miss the update statement in the trigger, ie after selecting `class` from `f_class` add

```
update salary_class set how_many = how_many + 1 where class = :letter;
```